# Trouble parsing custom structure with shell script utilities like sed / awk / grep

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to use a shell script to parse a complex list of structures out of a text file, and search those structures for a very specific set of values. If there is a match then I need to print the values of one variable. I am ***limited to*** lightweight utilities like ***sed, awk, and grep (but not Perl)***.

Here is an example of the structure, followed by an explanation of what I am looking for:

```
{
    { 1, 2, 
        { 15, 25 },
        { 15, 25 }
    },
    { 3, 4,
        { 35, 45 },
        { 35, 45 }
    },
    { 5, 6,
        { 55, 65 },
        { 55, 65 }
    }
};
```

In this example I would be parsing the three structures and searching for a structure which has a "3" as the first value, has any single digit (0-9) as the second value, and at least one set of "35" and "45" in the inner list of structures. Once I have located a match I would then print the value of the second value. In this case the second structure would match, and I would need to print out the value "4".

I don't want to assume anything about how the whitespace is organized, only that the format above is followed. I.e. it could all be on a single line or have different combinations of line breaks in random places.

Can someone please help me think about how to approach this problem?

Comment: Of the "lightweight" utilities, awk is the "heaviest" and will have to be your workhorse for counting the nesting levels. But awk is line-oriented (not character-), so your first step is to write code that guarantees that every `{` and `}` are on their own line alone (optionally removing any surrounding spaces in the process). Give that a shot first. Update the question with what you find.

Comment: Can there be more or less nesting levels than that or is it ALWAYS 3 levels deep? Post the expected output you'd want from that sample input.

Comment: I've experimented with different ways to remove or simplify the formatting, but the structure itself is related to what I'm searching for, so I want to be careful not to lose required information.

I need to be able to treat each structure as a separate item. I need to be able to search the first two values against expected values, and I need to search the "inner list" to look for an expected pair of values.

My first thought was to use sed with one long regular expression that specified the pattern and then to use a capture group to print the value I was looking for. I'm still working on it.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Since that's not what you're doing, sed would be the wrong tool for the job. This is 100% a job for awk. If you don't know awk, get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn it.

Comment: @EdMorton it's guaranteed not to be nested any deeper / differently than the format shown. The only things which are variable is that those inner pairs can be lists from 1 to many, and the outer list of structures itself can be 1 to many.

Comment: OK then edit your question to include your expected output and I expect someone will post a simple awk script to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Are commas enforced part of syntax?  Your first block second entry `{ 15, 25 }` is missing the trailing comma.  The others have it.

Comment: @karakfa The final commas are not there in the real data, it was a typo which I have corrected. Thank you for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1):

this may be what you want, using GNU awk for various extensions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="[{}]"; FS="\\s*,\\s*" }
depth == 2 { split($0,outer) }
(depth == 3) && (outer[1]==3) && (outer[2]~/^[0-9]$/) &&
    ((($1==35) && ($2==45)) || (($1==45) && ($2==35))) { print outer[2] }
{ depth = depth + (RT=="{" ? 1 : -1) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
4
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-robust `awk` attempt

```
$  awk -F"[{,}]" '/{/ && !/}/{c=($2==3)?+$3:""} 
   c~/^[0-9]$/ && $2==35 && $3==45{print c;exit}' file
4
```

using the layout

Comment: Originally answered my own question in the comments, moving it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help on this one. I was able to eventually solve it using only sed and tr, although it wasn't pretty. I used tr to join all of the lines together, then sed to remove the outer { };, sed again to split the lines along structure boundaries by using backrefrences, sed again to cleanup commas and whitespace between structures, and then "sed -n -r "s//\1/p" to validate the expected values in pattern, and to print only the matching variable.

I will take a look at your examples and see if I can learn from them.